# what does this function signature mean?

Tags: scala

I came across this function signature

```
def foldMapP[A, B : Monoid](values: Iterable[A])(func: A => B = (a: A) => a): Future[B] = ???
```

So this declares a function which takes and A and returns a B and then what is that `=` after B?

Comment: interesting. `function: A=> B = (a: A) => a` seems to be default function which maps to whatever is given as input, if you don not specify a specific function from A to B. I am guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`func` is type `A => B` but it has a default value of "just return the `A` part". So you can invoke `foo` without an argument and it will use the default function.

Comment: `A` and `B` are not required to be different. You're right, it won't compile if invoked `foo[Int,Char]()` but if `A` and `B` are inferred by the compiler then `foo()` should compile and run.

Comment: Do we not require at least one of view bound `A <% B` or context bound `A <: B` for this `foo` to compile ?

Comment: I just checked... we do not actually need a view bound.... Scala allows this default function paramter... but why or how can we pass function `(a: A) => a` for a parameter of type `A => B` without bounds between A and B ?

Comment: Ok... I understand now. Was thinking too much to notice this simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have written, the syntax is for a default parameter value, but I'd like to point out an interesting thing about its type. 
So the function takes a function from A to B and - if none provided it'll default to a basic identity function in A.

So how can a parameter of type A => B have a default value of type A => A?

Strange as it may seem, but this compiles. Calling it without a parameter passed however, will only compile if type parameters A and B are explicitly stated or inferred to be the same type.

So foo[String, Int] should not, while foo[Int, Int] should compile if I'm not mistaken. I'm not sure what would happen about foo without explicit type params however, maybe a not very helpful [Nothing, Nothing] inferred?

Comment: yes, this something still puzzles me. how can you return a default `a` when function signature is `B`.

Answer (score 0):

This is called an optional parameter with a default value. Basically,

```
def foo(x: Int = 42) = ???
```

means: `x` is of type `Int` and if the caller doesn't pass an argument, use `42` instead.

E.g.:

```
def foo(x: Int = 42) = x

foo(23) //=> 23
foo()   //=> 42
```

as opposed to:

```
def bar(x: Int) = x

bar(23) //=> 23
bar()   //ERROR
```